# Shared memory in matrix multiply involving multiple processes

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to learn IPC via shared memory . I don't understand one thing how do I allocate shared memory to various variables of different processes.For example , in a matrix multiplication i don't want to declare matrix globally but via shared memory . How do we attach memory to different matrices as :

Could anyone help me with this ? Also , can it be replaced by mmap() and shm_open() or is it just files ? If yes , how ? I could not find apt examples in which how shared memory is modified by the processes is illustrated .

Comment: `*shmem_ptr = value;`, perhaps?

Comment: if you need to use shared memory, use the modern version of it, `shm_open` together with `mmap` and `munmap`. It is much simpler to use and has less restrictions. Generally, the code that you posted is a real mess and wouldn't even compile. Please clean your things up before you post here.

Comment: I just wanted to convey the concept ...but I don't know how it will be replaced by shm_open and mmap and munmap !!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Don't use shared memory for IPC. It's messy.

In most situations where shared memory would make sense, it's easier and more appropriate to just use threads (so that *all* memory is shared). When that isn't possible, you're probably better off using some sort of message-passing scheme.

> How do I allocate memory from this shared memory for matrix A , B and resultant matrix and
>   attach to it as I don't have to declare matrices globally and each process would need A B C to do
>    part of problem.

You'd have to come up with some way to allocate memory within the shared memory segment. You can't use `malloc()` for this, since its arena doesn't include the shared memory.

If the only data you're going to store is going to be those three matrices, **and** the size of those matrices is known to both processes, you could just stack them all into a structure and store that in the segment:

```
struct shm_data {
    float A[123][123], B[123][123], C[123][123];
};

struct shm_data *mat = (struct shm_data *) shm;
```

If the size of the matrices isn't fixed, though, you'd have to figure their addresses at runtime.

> Also , can it be replaced by mmap() and shm_open() or is it just files ?

Yes. In fact, `mmap()` is almost universally preferable to `shm_open()`, as the memory segment is backed by a file and obeys filesystem semantics, so it can be cleaned up sensibly. POSIX shared memory (which is what you're using) is much weirder.

Comment: If I can't use global variables in different processes , where do I declare struct containing matrices, rows and columns ?